# Getting list of all variables in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way to copy text into buffer all the variables local and inherited for a particular class?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried)

Comment: I don't understand a single word... what is it again you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using an external tool like **[javap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html)** to quickly list all instance variables of a class (in the stdout, which you can easily copy).

> The `javap` command disassembles a class file.
>   Its output depends on the options used.
>   If no options are used, `javap` prints out the package, **protected, and public fields and methods of the classes passed to it**. `javap` prints its output to `stdout`.

You can call it as an [external tool from your eclipse session](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t78557.html#92053647):

> - `Run>External Tools`. This brings up the external tool launch wizard.
> - Select `Program`, and give a name, "`javap`".
> - For "`Location:`", hit the browser file system, and find where your `javap` app is located.
> - For "`Working Directory`", select "`Browse Workspace...`", and choose your workspace where your class file is located.
>     For example, I have a project in my workspace called `helloDB`, after I selected this project, the test box will update to: `${workspace_loc:/helloDB}`.
>     I don't think `javap` uses this directly, but you can use it for the "`Arguments:`" section.
> - My `helloDB.class` file is located in my `bin` directory relative to my project.
>     So for "`Arguments:`", so for my project I entered: `-classpath ${workspace_loc:/helloDB}/bin helloDB`
>     Note: there's a space between `.../bin` and `helloDB`. The `helloDB` is my `.class` file.
> - Hit run